# Cerrar Menu Slide desde Tab Bar Controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Tengo un menu slide personalizado que se abre con un button, cuando se abre me gustaria poder cerrarlo dando clic en el mismo tab bar item donde es llamado. Uso lo que son animaciones para la transicion.

Como puedo hacer eso? Anexo mi codigo.

Esta parte es para mostrar el menu cuando dan clic en el boton de mi view controller

```
@IBAction func buttonListenerMenuHome(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //REFERENCIAMOS DEL STORYBOARD EL MENU (OPTIONAL)
    guard let menuTableViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ID_MenuHome") as? MenuTableViewController
        else { return }
    func TransicionContenido(_ menuType:MenuType) {
        switch menuType {
        case .health:
            break;
        case .construction:
            break;
        case .retail:
            break;
        case .education:
            break;
        case .entertainment:
            break;
        case .environment:
            break;
        case .finance:
            break;
        case .energy:
            break;
        case .telecom:
            break;
        case .about:
            break;
        }
    }
    menuTableViewController.menuHomeMenuType = {menuType in
        TransicionContenido(menuType)
    }
    //PRESENTAMOS EL MENU
    menuTableViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    menuTableViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
    //self.view.addSubview(menuTableViewController.view!)
    //self.addChild(menuTableViewController)
    present(menuTableViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Esta parte es la extension del mismo view controller donde muestro el menu

```
extension HomeViewController:UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    MainTabBarController.scrollShape.isHidden = true
    tabBarController!.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.init(named: "ItemNoSeleccionado")
    transicion.estadoMenu = true
    return transicion
}
func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    transicion.estadoMenu = false
    MainTabBarController.scrollShape.isHidden = false
    tabBarController!.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.init(named: "ItemSeleccionado")
    return transicion
}
```

}

Esta es la clase donde realizo la animacion de transicion del menu slide

```
class TransicionSide: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
//BANDERA QUE NOS INDICA CUANDO SE ABRE O SE CIERRA EL MENU
var estadoMenu:Bool = false

let degradadoView = UIView()

//METODOS NECESARIOS DEL PROTOCOLO DE UIVIEWCONTROLLERANIMATEDTRANSITIONING
func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return 0.3
}

func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    guard let aViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to),
        let deViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) else { return }

    let contenedorView = transitionContext.containerView

    let widthFinal = aViewController.view.bounds.width * (0.8)
    let heightFinal = deViewController.view.bounds.height

    func transform2 () {
        self.degradadoView.alpha = 0.5
        aViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -widthFinal, y: 0)
    }

    func identity () {
        self.degradadoView.alpha = 0.0
        deViewController.view.transform = .identity
    }

    // ANIMACION PARA CUANDO APAREZCA EN PANTALLA EL MENU
    let transform = {
        self.degradadoView.alpha = 0.5
        aViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -widthFinal, y: 0)
    }

    //ANIMACION PARA CUANDO SALGA DE LA PANTALLA EL MENU
    let identity = {
        self.degradadoView.alpha = 0.0
        deViewController.view.transform = .identity
    }

    if estadoMenu == true {

        //AGREGAMOS AL CONTENEDOR LA VISTA DEGRADADA



        degradadoView.backgroundColor = .black
        degradadoView.alpha = 0.0
        contenedorView.addSubview(degradadoView)
        degradadoView.frame = contenedorView.bounds

        //SE AGREGA EL MENU AL CONTENEDOR
        contenedorView.addSubview(aViewController.view)

        //SE INICIA AFUERA DE LA PANTALLA
        aViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: aViewController.view.bounds.width, y: 0, width: widthFinal, height: heightFinal)
    }

    //ANIMACION DE LA TRANSICION
    let duracion = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
    let esCancelado = transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duracion, animations: {
        if self.estadoMenu == true {
            transform()
        } else if self.estadoMenu == false {
            identity()
        }

        //self.estadoMenu ? transform() : identity()
    }) {(_) in
        transitionContext.completeTransition(!esCancelado)
    }
}
```

}

Y por ultimo esta es la clase de mi table view controller donde creo el menu para mi pantalla

```
enum MenuType:Int {
case health
case construction
case retail
case education
case entertainment
case environment
case finance
case energy
case telecom
case about
```

}
class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var nombreController:String = "MenuTableViewController"

var transicion = TransicionSide()

var menuHomeMenuType:((MenuType) -> Void)?


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let menuType = MenuType(rawValue: indexPath.row) else { return }

    dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
        print("\(self!.nombreController) ---> Cerrando menu, se selecciono: \(menuType)")
        self!.menuHomeMenuType?(menuType)
    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("\(nombreController) ---> ESTOY EN VIEW WILL DISAPPEAR")


    dismiss(animated: false)

}
```

}

Espero me puedan ayudar soy novato en el desarrollo en iOS.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Saludos, porque mezclas elementos de UI que no deben ir juntos, en iOS los tabBar se usan para mostrar pestañas x regla si hay un tabbar en la UI no hay menú una des las pestañas con contiene opciones o un menú pero se muestra como una vista normal no se desplaza sobre el tabbarr te recomiendo que te leas el apple human interface guidelines  o HID en I goes para que entiendas algo del diseño en iOS y puedas entender porque ese acercamiento en iOS no se usa ni es Agar le a los usuarios

Comment: Te lo agradezco mucho!.

Entonces esa operación es imposible?

Comment: imposible no pero si una mala elección de UI en IOS. te sugiero cambiarla de hecho si tienes un tiempo dale una lectura a este enlace https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/overview/themes/

Comment: Te lo agradezco mucho! Y más por tu tiempo! Dare lectura para aprender más